# Не получается авторизоватся вконтакте через curl

Tags: curl, php

Никак не выходит авторизоваться вконтакте

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)'); // чтобы сайт думал, что мы - браузер:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // ответ сервера будем записывать в переменную
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"CP1251\""
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // по редиректам будем переходить автоматически.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://vk.com/?email=$mail&pass=$pass');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
echo $answer;
```

Comment: Мне кажется, нужно отказаться от *`http_build_query`*.

Попробуйте просто в виде массива (`$key=>$val`) передать...

Comment: у меня post вообще не используется,все решает следующая строчка(из браузера работает на ура)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://vk.com/?email=$mail&pass=$pass');

Comment: сессия и куки поможет. Укажите где надо хранить их.

Comment: Гм. Я надеюсь, что ошибаюсь, но: если у вас и правда данные логина содержатся в переменных `$mail` и `$pass`, замените

    'http://vk.com/?email=$mail&pass=$pass'
    на
    "http://vk.com/?email=$mail&pass=$pass"

ибо в строке с одинарными кавычками переменные не парсятся.

Comment: насчет ковычек - да, согласен, что-то я тупанул, но всеравно не работает

Comment: кукисы прописал, только мне от них пока толку нет, мне надо для начала авторизоватся, может дело в кодировке? мой сайт в utf-8, а контакт в 1251.

Comment: @Роман, во первых, там не ГЕТ,а ПОСТ форма.

Я у вас никак не могу найти *CURLOPT_POST* опцию.

Answer (score 1):

1. Про сессию и куки [@vfvtnjd](/users/4996/vfvtnjd) уже написал. Возможно, облом ещё и из-за того, что не обрабывается JavaScript - скажем, проверяется его функциональность. Чтобы обойти потенциальную проблему с JS, прикидывайтесь мобильным клиентом и ломитесь на `m.vk.com`;
2. оно вам точно надо — имитировать бразуер? Уверены, что стандартными средствами [vk API](https://vk.com/developers.php?o=-1&p=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_API_%D0%92%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5&s=0) не решаются задачи? Парсинг страниц — нарушение правил ВК, могут зажопить рано или поздно : )

Comment: 1.никто не знает что я парсю
2. я не хочу чтобы сайт спрашивал разрешения у пользователя(лишнее действие)
3.я не совсем разобрался как это все провернуть через vk api